# How to remove the grey background behind JCheckboxes?

Tags: java, swing, jcheckbox

I want to remove the grey background that appears automatically when creating JCheckboxes. The panel that the JCheckboxes are in, is setOpaque(false). I have tried using setOpaque(false) with the JCheckboxes but it doesn't work. I want to make the JCheckboxes appear directly on the black background as in the image.

JCheckboxes grey background on black background:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MeaRc.png]

My code is below. An arraylist was used to retrieve data from the database n display them as JCheckboxes. The ModulePanel was then added to the JFrame.

```
            Enrol= new JCheckBox(Modules.get(i));       
            ModulePanel.add(Enrol);
```

Comment: For better help sooner please post a valid [mcve]

Comment: `ModulePanel.setOpaque(false);`? Agree with @Frakcool re posting an MCVE. Also, please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently.

Answer (score 3):

First of all variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. Learn from the examples in your text book or tutorial.

Using `setOpaque(false)` on the check box works fine for me.

> I want to make the JCheckboxes appear directly on the black background as in the image.

Looks like you are adding a panel containing the checkboxes to the component displaying the image.

I would guess the problem is that you also need to use `setOpaque(false)` on the panel that contains the checkboxes.

Answer (score 1):

> I have tried using setOpaque(false) with the JCheckboxes but it doesn't work

Well, that's the right way to do it.

For example, try setting the background of the panel where the boxes are held to other color and call your `checkBox.setOpaque(false);`

For example:

[image]

```
import java.awt.Color;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class CheckBoxNoBackground {
    private JFrame frame;
    private JPanel pane;
    private JCheckBox box1;
    private JCheckBox box2;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new CheckBoxNoBackground().createAndShowGui());
    }

    public void createAndShowGui() {
        frame = new JFrame(getClass().getSimpleName());

        pane = new JPanel();
        pane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(pane, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

        box1 = new JCheckBox("I'm a check box");
        box2 = new JCheckBox("I'm also a check box");

        box1.setOpaque(false);
        pane.setBackground(Color.CYAN);

        pane.add(box1);
        pane.add(box2);

        frame.add(pane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

> The panel that the JCheckboxes are in, is setOpaque(false).

If you do that, you're seeing the background of the `JFrame`'s content pane (which is gray)

If I add this line:

```
pane.setOpaque(false);
```

I get this:

[image]

However if you want more help on your code, post a valid MCVE as said before in the comments.